# show the following strengthened version of the Markov property

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

(Markov property) Suppose we have a Markov chain X = {$X_t$}$^∞_0$ with a countable state space S.
For each t in {0, 1, 2,... }, the random variable $X_t$ takes values in S.
The matrix P is stochastic, that is, p(i, j)>= 0 for all i, j in S and

$\sum\limits_{j\in S} p(i,j)=1$ for all $i \in S$.

(Markov property) For any t in {0, 1, 2,... } and for any states $i_0,...,i_{t-1},$ i, j in S,
$P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i, X_{t-1} = i_{t-1},...,X_0 = i_0) = p(i, j).$
For this reason, p(i, j) is called a transition probability.

Using that Markov property, show the following strengthened version
of the Markov property:

Let t ≥ 0, x, y ∈ S, and A ⊆ $S^t$
. Then
$P(X_t+1 = y | X_t = x,(X_0, . . . , X_t−1) ∈ A)
= P(X_t+1 = y | X_t = x)
= P_x(X_1 = y)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is your definition of the Markov property? The first equality for me looks like the usual Markov property, and the second equality is true if you are considering a time homogeneous Markov chain.